# Why two layers of matrix multiplication is needed in CBOW and Skip-gram model?

Tags: neural-networks, word2vec, language-models

I found a nice tutorial [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~ronxin/pdf/w2vexp.pdf) regarding CBOW and Skip-gram models for Word2Vec. I got the following doubt:

Why two layers of matrix multiplication is need for CBOW and SKIP-GRAM ? As multiplying a vector with a Matrix followed by another matrix can be written as multiplication by an equivalent single matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying a vector with a matrix A followed by another matrix B can be written as multiplication by an equivalent single matrix. However, the number of elements in the matrix AB can be much higher than number of elements in the matrix A + number of elements in the matrix B.

---

Example in CBOW:

[image]

$A = W$, $B = W'$. The number of elements in the matrix AB is $N^2$, while the number of elements in the matrix A + number of elements in the matrix B is $2VN$. (and $V \gg  N$). Hence the use of two distinct matrices.